# Changing mm/dd/yyyy and m/dd/yyyy to yyyy

Tags: r

I have a data set with the dates written as follows:

5/18/12
12/20/10
2/17/08

etc

Is there a way to transform these into yyyy format? I'm struggling because they didn't include 0s in front of the months, so each date is a different number of characters long.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.Date` with `format` in `base R`

```
format(as.Date(c("5/18/12", "12/20/10", "2/17/08"), "%m/%d/%y") , "%Y")
#[1] "2012" "2010" "2008"
```

Comment: I have about 8000 observations with dates like these... is there a way to apply this to all the obsercations?

Comment: @Sofia Definitely.  If your column is 'date' as name in the dataset.  `df1$year <- format(as.Date(df1date, "%m/%d/%y") , "%Y")` this creates a new column 'year' in the same dataset

Answer (score 0):

Using the `lubridate` package you need to convert the string to dates and then you can just pull out the year with the aptly named `year` function

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- c("5/18/12", "12/20/10", "2/17/08")
dates <- as_date(dates,format = "%m/%d/%y", tz = "UTC" )
year(dates)
```

which gives:

> [1] 2012 2010 2008